# Open Word Doc with Pages using Applescript

Tags: applescript, ms-office, pages

How can I get the following to work in Pages? I get an error message saying the file can't be opened but if I change the path to a `.pages` file it works fine.

```
tell application "Pages"
  activate
  open "/tmp/test.docx"
end tell
```

Comment: I can open the file using the Pages open file dialog just fine.

Comment: It worked okay for me.  This also works: `do shell script "open -a Pages /path_to/filename.docx"`